# Query join dates with dates from the seim table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a query in sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

and the output of the query is:

```
4     casa       perro
89    apartment  mula
12    casa       gato
31    roor       mouse
43    apartment  zorro
19    roor       sapo
        .
        .
        .
```

And in the second column i have 2 rows for each element, i have 2 rows with casa, 2 rows with apartment, 2 rows with roor, ...

i need a query that show me the seim element.

For example the output:

```
4    perro    12    gato   casa
89   mula     43    zorro  apartment
31   mouse    19    sapo   roor
```

Comment: What database are you using?  This is tagged both MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: what are you asking..?? This question is not clear.? what is this.. `i have 2 for each element, i have 2 casa, 2 apartment, 2 roor` be specific and technical while you ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption is that you're using MySql (this tag goes first in your question).

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT col1, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN id   END) id1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN col2 END) col21,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN id   END) id2,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN col2 END) col22       
  FROM 
(
  SELECT t.*, @n := IF(@g = col1, @n + 1, 1) rnum, @g := col1
    FROM Table1 t, (SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY col1, id
) q
 GROUP BY col1
```

Sample output:

```
|      COL1 | ID1 | COL21 | ID2 | COL22 |
-----------------------------------------
| apartment |  43 | zorro |  89 |  mula |
|      casa |   4 | perro |  12 |  gato |
|      roor |  19 |  sapo |  31 | mouse |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/875bb/7)** demo

---

Now you can take different approach and pack `id` and `col2` values with `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`, using different separators,  into one column (let's call it `details`). And then [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it on the client while you iterate over the resultset.

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(id, '|', col2)) details
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY col1
```

Sample output:

```
|      COL1 |          DETAILS |
--------------------------------
| apartment | 89|mula,43|zorro |
|      casa |  4|perro,12|gato |
|      roor | 31|mouse,19|sapo |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/875bb/8)** demo

Comment: Tag order is determined by SO not the questioner. The tags are sorted by popularity.  More questions are tagged [mysql] than are tagged [oracle] so [mysql] comes first.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?